# Why Is This List Assignment Index Out of Range?

Tags: python, list, append

I'm working on a simple left circular shift function as an exercise (ie feed it `[1,2,3]` and it returns `[[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]]`). If I use this version of the code:

```
def left_shifts(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        M = []
    elif len(L) == 1:
        M = deepcopy(L)
    else:
        M = [len(L)]
        M[0] = L
        for i in range(1,len(L)):
            M[i] = (L[i:] + L[:i])

    return M

print (left_shifts([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

I get an error that the list assignment index is out of range. However, if I just tweak it to this:

```
def left_shifts(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        M = []
    elif len(L) == 1:
        M = deepcopy(L)
    else:
        M = [len(L)]
        M[0] = L
        for i in range(1,len(L)):
            M.append((L[i:] + L[:i])) #changed line

    return M

print (left_shifts([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

It works fine. My question is: why would the upper code generate this error? All I'm doing is adding two lists together and assigning it to one element of another list, which I would think would be legal.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: That's not an applicable. I think the OP thought that `M = [len(L)]` created a list of `len(L)` elements, at which point it is not unreasonable to think that `M[1]` exists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - The answer explains the exact problem. I think it's a precise duplicate.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: it doesn't cover `[integer]`, then expecting `integer` number of elements to exist.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - The only possibility for an even closer duplicate would basically be "how do I create a list in Python?", which would be answered by any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M = [len(L)]` creates a list with *one element*, an integer:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> len(L)
3
>>> [len(L)]
[3]
```

This is why `M[1]` doesn't exist; you have a list of length 1 so only index `0` exists.

If you expected that to create a list with `len(L)` elements, you'd need to use multiplication:

```
M = [None] * len(L)
```

This creates a list with `len(L)` references to `None`. Don't use list multiplication for mutable objects however; `[...] * N` doesn't create copies of the contents; you get `N` references to the same contents. This matters when those contents themselves are mutable.

Not that your code needs to be this complicated. Just use a list comprehension:

```
def left_shifts(L):
    return [L[i:] + L[:i] for i in range(len(L))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def left_shifts(L):
...     return [L[i:] + L[:i] for i in range(len(L))]
...
>>> left_shifts([1, 2, 3])
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: "What should indices 0 through to 41 all be set to in that case?" - Some languages allow sparse arrays, and they generally use a null value (or 0, or garbage data).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: There are sparse array implementations for Python too, but Python lists aint such a beast. Sparse arrays are specialised structures, not suited to be a general sequence workhorse like `list` is.  :-)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I dropped the index assignment vs. appending altogether, as I'm now pretty sure the OP meant to create a list of `len(L)` elements.

Comment: This is true, I'm coming from a C/C++ background and didn't realize this syntax doesn't carry over to Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to explain this is by modifying your code slightly:

```
def left_shifts(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        M = []
    elif len(L) == 1:
        M = deepcopy(L)
    else:
        M = [len(L)]
        print(M)
    return M

print (left_shifts([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

So I changed it to print what you just assigned M to.

It outputs:

```
[5]
```

You just made an array with the number 5 in it...  Array definitions in Python don't work this way.  Python uses a unique syntax. Additionally, [] defines a list, not an array.

Just use the append function.

New code:

```
def left_shifts(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        M = []
    elif len(L) == 1:
        M = deepcopy(L)
    else:
        M = []
        M.append(L)
        for i in range(1,len(L)):
            M.append((L[i:] + L[:i])) #changed line

    return M

print (left_shifts([1,2,3,4,5]))
```